# How to set a CardView widget above an appBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to have a card widget starting above an appBarLayout, and continuing above the white background that follows. Above this card I need to have and ImageView (at the top-center), and two floating buttons (at the bottom-right). Half of those elements are on the card, the other half is out.

My issues are : i have no shadows below my card, and the buttons are cut in half.

Here's what i got so far :
[image: screenshot]
layout_card_detailed.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_detail_avatar_margin"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_detail_padding"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_big" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_owner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/space_big" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_avatar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size_detail"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size_detail"
            android:src="@drawable/contact"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-28dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_match"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_reply"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_card_detail.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myapp.CardDetailActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin">
        <include layout="@layout/layout_card_detailed"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, i had to use CoordinatorLayout instead of FrameLayout.
Everything works good now, appart from the fact that my FAB shadows are cut in an abrupt way, following the square shape of the original android view.
If anyone as an idea i'm interested :-).

layout_card_detailed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_detail_avatar_margin">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_progress_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_progress_size"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_loading"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_detail_padding"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_big" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_owner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_networks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/space_big" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_match"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin">


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_avatar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size_detail"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size_detail"
            android:src="@drawable/contact"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```